# How to run a program as elevated in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, excel, uac, elevated-privileges, vba

I created an application in Excel VBA that needs to run a batch file out of script and I was wondering how I can elevate all the processes that the process creates. Please I need to know how to elevate processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an EXE, you can embed a **manifest** it that will make it require adminrights on Windows 7/Vista.

**Edit:** The entire that does this manifest would be:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
        <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="False" />
        </requestedPrivileges>
     </security>
    </trustInfo>
  </assembly>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable"
                uiAccess="False" />
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>

Comment: So this on top of the manifest file or is this the entire file with a return at the bottom?

Comment: You're welcome :) I edited my original answer to include it :)

Comment: How is the OP going to embed the manifest in Excel.exe compiled by Microsoft?